# Retrieve data sent from ajax post request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am sending JSON formatted data using ajax post request, and I want to retrieve the data from the file that data was sent to.
If you do not know how many objects are in a JSON variable and you do not know the keys, how can you retrieve the data using $_POST["name"]; ?

The website I am currently working on is like a simple online store, and the customer can choose any items however many times. I am for now storing the date in localStorage. The JSON data will be like {"itemName":"item's name", "number": "the number of the items they want"}, and it cannot be expected how many different items the customer buys. When placeOrder button is pressed, I want to send the purchase information in JSON format, and I want to parse it in php file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".placeOrder").click(function(){
        var purchaseInfo = {}; //make JSON formatted variable
        var key, item;
        //move all localStorage data (which contains the item and the number)
        //to purchaseInfo 
        for(var i=0; i<localStorage.length; i++){
            key = localStorage.key(i);
            item = localStorage.getItem(key);
            purchaseInfo[key] = item;
        }


        //ADDED THIS CODE
        purchaseInfo = {"productPurchased":purchaseInfo};

        //send the data to place_order.php 
        $.ajax({
            url: "place_order.php",
            data: purchaseInfo,
            method: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                alert("success");
                //change the page using location.href
                window.location.href = "place_order.php";
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert("failed");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

After sending purchaseInfo varibale to place_order.php, I am not sure how to parse the content of the variable.. Could anyone help me get the idea here? Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT:
The ajax function and how I (tried to) move the data of localStorage to a variable **purchaseInfo** in JSON format, are shown above.

In place_order.php (where I am trying to retrieve the JSON data and compute more so I can calculate the total price)

```
    <?php
        //this line below prints NULL           
        var_dump($_POST["productPurchased"]);

        //and this code below prints "I am empty"
        if("" == trim($_POST["productPurchased"])){
            echo "I am empty";
        }else{
            echo "I am filled";
        }

        //$purchaseInfo = $_POST['productPurchased'];
        //the below line of code prints "array(0) { } "
        var_dump($_POST);            
    ?>
```

Comment: Start with `print_r($_POST)` and showing output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript:

```
purchaseInfo = {'purchaseInfo': purchaseInfo};
$.ajax({ ...
```

In PHP:

```
$purchaseInfo = $_POST['purchaseInfo'];
// Do smth with data in $purchaseInfo
```

Now in PHP `$purchaseInfo` is an associative array with items from localStorage.

Comment: Thanks! For example, purchaseInfo has a variable like {"notebook": "2", "pen": "10", "whiteout": "1"} where the first one is the name of products the customer selected and the second one is the number of each item. Now, I added purchaseInfo = {"productPurchased", purchaseInfo} in JavaScript, and I added $purchaseInfo = $_POST['productPurchased']; but I am not sure I can access the data (name of the product and the quantity)

Comment: I tried: foreach($purchaseInfo as $key => $value) and tried to echo both $key and $value, but nothing is printed on the browser.

Comment: It prints NULL.

Comment: It's impossible. `$_POST` is a superglobal array. It can't be null. Show me full code you execute, please.

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help, Sir! I added my code in the question.

Comment: Ok. Then show what exactly `var_dump($_POST);` prints. Not `var_dump($_POST["dataForConfirmation"]);`

Comment: var_dump($_POST) prints "array(0) { } ".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132702/discussion-between-german-lashevich-and-wang-dang).